# Deploy Related list in salesforce package

Tags: salesforce

I have a "related list" in my `Account` layout as there is a master detail relationship.How do I add the related list layout in the package so that when the other person installs it , can be seen in his Account Layout

Answer (score 0):

You can include page layouts in your package, just choose it from the drop down and then select the layouts you want to include. If you include the Account page layouts in question then the related list will be there (assuming you include the custom object as well!):

Choose "Page Layout"
[image: Choose "Page Layout"]

Choose the Account page layouts you want to include
[image: Choose the appropriate layouts to include]

Comment: When i added it into my package and then tried to install in other developer account it says conflict in accounts Layout cant install